# Moving android sdk

Tags: android, sdk

Guys I have installed my SDK in some other drive than C(Windows drive), but while running for first time studio created a folder in default location having some of he components downloaded or installed there. So I was wondering should I just copy the contents of SDK from the place I have installed and copy in default location and start using from there (change path). Because it is useless and maybe more work for system to fetch half of the components from 1 place and half from other, because the 2 folders are in 2 different partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files of SDk are independent from the files created bt android studio.So no need to copy the sdk files and place at default directory.